# dialogflow.com - How to integrate with Google Home / Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-home

I am working on an e-commerce website and would like to integrate with Google Voice assistant or Amazon alexa. I have gone through the [dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) on how to build a voice assistant. But how It'll be available in amazon alexa or google home that shipped to every household ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Alexa and Google Assistant let you develop things that work very much like websites - Alexa calls them Skills, Google calls them Actions. These are programs that run on your (or a) web server, get HTTPS calls from Amazon or Google with JSON information about what the user has said, and are expected to return JSON information that replies to what has been said.

Amazon requires you to use the Alexa Skills Kit to do the development of these sites, but Dialogflow can [export its model to Alexa](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/#amazon_alexa_and_microsoft_cortana). Google is a little more open, but since they own Dialogflow, [integrating a Dialogflow agent with Actions](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/actions/) on Google is very straightforward.

You will need to register your Skill/Action with the appropriate company, but once you have done so, it is available to the users. Alexa users need to "install" the Skill from the Skills directory, although that really just means that they can activate it. The Assistant doesn't require users to activate it this way, but it will be listed in the directory. In both cases, users can then trigger it by saying something like "open Skill Name" or "talk to Action Name".